# MySQL Order By not using ASC or DESC

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a column using IDs that I want to sort by.  It has ID values from 1 to 3.  However, instead of just using ASC of DESC, I want to do a custom sort by 2, 3, 1.  How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '2,3,1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a virtual column with values would be

```
MOD(ID, 3)
```

and order your query ascending by it. For example:

```
SELECT somecolumn, MOD(ID, 3) AS ordered_id FROM my_table ORDER BY ordered_id
```

Comment: This absolutely works, but it should be noted that if the table has more than 3 IDs, this query has to be altered manually (which isn't the biggest deal, but the purist in me struggles, ha!).

Comment: Hmmm... why does this work? 2/3/1 MOD 3 results in 2/0/1. Don't you need to use MOD(ID+1, 3)?

Comment: It might work, but it's a very bad solution as the MOD()s for the complete table have to be calculated before selecting some rows out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
SELECT ..., IF(ID=2, 1, IF(ID=3, 2, 3)) AS orderByValue
  FROM ...
 ORDER BY orderByValue
```

It uses the [IF function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html) to convert ID values:

```
 ID     orderByValue
  2        1
  3        2
else       3
```